# Celery + RabbitMQ - Use Celery for simple messaging

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

In my Django project I implemented Celery, which is running using RabbitMQ backend.

### What celery does:

`Celery` puts my tasks into queue, and then under certain conditions runs them. That being said, I basically interact with `RabbitMQ` message queue exclusively using `Celery` python interface.

### Problem:

I want just to push simple string message into `RabbitMQ` queue, which should be consumed by 3rd party application.

### What I tried:

There is a way how to directly connect to `RabbitMQ` using [Pika library](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html). However I would find it a little clunky - If I have already `Celery` connected  to `RabbitMQ`, why not use it (if possible) to send simple messages to a specific queue, instead opening another connection using mentioned `Pika` library.

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Celery to send arbitrary messages to your RabbitMQ server.

However, considering that you already use RabbitMQ as a broker, which means you already have all the necesary RabbitMQ support ([py-amqp](https://github.com/celery/py-amqp) supports it either directly, or via [librabbitmq](https://pypi.org/project/librabbitmq)), you can easily send messages to the MQ server from your Celery tasks. If you for whatever reason do not like py-amqp, you may use Pika as you mentioned already.